# Python: concatenating bytes with a string

Tags: python, string, md5

I'm working on a python project in 2.6 that also has future support for python 3 being worked in.  Specifically I'm working on a digest-md5 algorithm.

In python 2.6 without running this import:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

I am able to write a piece of code such as this:

```
a1 = hashlib.md5("%s:%s:%s" % (self.username, self.domain, self.password)).digest() 
a1 = "%s:%s:%s" %(a1, challenge["nonce"], cnonce )
```

Without any issues, my authentication works fine.  When I try the same line of code with the unicode_literals imported I get an exception:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa8 in position 0: unexpected code byte

Now I'm relatively new to python so I'm a bit stuck in figuring this out.  if I replace the %s in the formatting string as %r I am able to concatenate the string, but the authentication doesn't work.  The digest-md5 spec that I had read says that the 16 octet binary digest must be appended to these other strings.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Python 3.x clearly separates strings from byte arrays. Depending on your needs, it *might* work to prepend the patterns `"%s:%s:%s"` with `b` to get a byte array, but that might well give the wrong results. What is the purpose of this code anyway?

Comment: This is a snippet of a larger piece of code that is used for a digest-md5 algorithm that I am using to authenticate against an xmpp server, and this is the specific piece of code that is causing me some issues.  

Pre-pending the formatting string with b still causes the same issue. 

Here is some more info on creating a digest-md5 http://web.archive.org/web/20050224191820/http://cataclysm.cx/wip/digest-md5-crash.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason for the behaviour you observed is that `from __future__ import unicode_literals` switches the way Python works with strings:

- In the 2.x series, strings without the *u* prefix are treated as sequences of bytes, each of which may be in the range \x00-\xff (inclusive). Strings with the *u* prefix are ucs-2 encoded unicode sequences.
- In Python 3.x -- as well as in the `unicode_literals` future, strings without the *u* prefix are unicode strings encoded in either UCS-2 or UCS-4 (depends on the compiler flag used when compiling Python). Strings with the *b* prefix are literals for the data type `bytes` which are rather similar to pre-3.x non-unicode strings.

In either version of Python, byte-strings and unicode-strings must be converted. The conversion performed by default depends on your system's default charset; in your case this is *UTF-8*. Without setting anything, it should be *ascii*, which rejects all characters above \x7f.

The message digest returned by hashlib.md5(...).digest() is a bytes-string, and I suppose you want the result of the whole operation to be a byte-string as well. If you want that, convert the nonce and cnonce-strings to byte-strings.:

```
a1 = hashlib.md5("%s:%s:%s"  % (self.username, self.domain, self.password)).digest()
# note that UTF-8 may not be the encoding required by your counterpart, please check
a1 = b"%s:%s:%s" %(a1, challenge["nonce"].encode("UTF-8"), cnonce.encode("UTF-8") )
```

Alternatively, you can convert the byte-string coming from the call to `digest()` to a unicode string (not recommended). As the lower 8 bit of UCS-2 are equivalent to ISO-8859-1, this might serve your needs:

```
a1 = hashlib.md5("%s:%s:%s"  % (self.username, self.domain, self.password)).digest()
a1 = "%s:%s:%s" %(a1.decode("ISO-8859-1"), challenge["nonce"], cnonce)
```

Comment: The first solution worked with the code.  Thank you for your insightful answer.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that "%s:%s:%s" became a unicode string once you imported unicode_literals.
The output of the hash is a "regular" string. Python tried to decode the regular string into a unicode string and failed (as expected. The hash output is supposed to look like noise).
Change your code to this:

```
a1 = a1 + str(':') + str(challenge["nonce"]) + str(':') + str(cnonce)
```

I'm assuming `cnonce` and `challenge["nonce"]` are regular strings. To have more control over their conversion to strings (if needed), use:

```
a1 += str(':') + challenge["nonce"].encode('UTF-8') + str(':') + cnonce.encode('UTF-8')
```